# Sylow subgroups for infinite groups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, infinite-groups

Is a characterisation/classification of (possibly infinite) groups known which have the property that any two $p$-Sylow subgroups are isomorphic for any $p$?

Comment: First you need to define what a $p$-Sylow subgroup means.  If you look at profinite groups, which are compact topological groups that are inverse limits of finite groups, the analogue (or rather, generalization) of a $p$-group in that setting is a pro-$p$ group, defined as profinite groups that are inverse limits of finite $p$-groups. A $p$-Sylow subgroup of a profinite group is defined as a pro-$p$-subgroup that is maximal relative to containment. Such subgroups exist by Zorn's lemma. For each prime $p$, all $p$-Sylow subgroups of a profinite group are conjugate.